# Matlab Impoint and Uicontrol

Tags: matlab, uicontrol

I'm more on the no0b side of coding, so I apologize in advance for stupid question and / or poor coding practice. Basically, I have a dream of being able to click, place an impoint, record the location of that impoint, and then click again for another point (and record the location of that point) until I hit the "Done" button. However, my code is going sideways.

My button is created with the line below. I've set the variable j to be 1 earlier on in the code, just because I wanted to be able to do two things with CallBack and so I wanted some way to indicate the the button has been clicked (I am, however, certainly not attached to this as  a method). When the user clicks the button, I would really like for 1) the loop for new impoints to stop and 2) the image to close.

uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Position',[80 0 70 20],'String','Done','CallBack','j=0;');

My loop for impoints (with extra stuff that I don't think is relevant removed) is as follows:

```
for k = 1:2*mboxes*nboxes
    if j == 0
        close(gcf);
        break;
    elseif j == 1
        fprintf('At line 56, j is %d and k is %d\n', j, k)
        h = impoint;
        setColor(h,'k');
        location = h.getPosition;
    end

    clear h;
end
```

At the moment, my problems are two-fold. Really, three-fold, but I can grudgingly live with the third problem. Problem 1, which is most concerning to me, is that I have to click the button just before I want to finish, which is to say that I click the button and then set down another point before the window will close. (In other words, it's going through the loop one time more than I want and I'm not sure how to tell it not to do that.) Problem 2, which I'm sure should tell me something about how it's looping, is that the impoints aren't being deleted as I go along (though h does seem to be deleted at the end). Problem 3, which is aesthetic but really annoys me, is that I keep getting a blue impoint in the upper left corner (0,0) of my image before I click where I actually want.

Any help would be much, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but I can only answer here not comment.... so what I guess:

Adressing your problem 2:
your h isn't deleted completly, try to use delete(h) instead of clear. This should also make your problem 3

Adressing your problem 1:
impoint get's your click position whereever you click I assume, even if you click on your button, so the two functions (get the impoint AND the click event) might overlap and give you that error. Maybe a look at the setPositionConstraintFcn can help you with this (enabling the click only for the area you want it to work).

Comment: maybe using a clickevent with the given axes a of your plot would be easier than impoint for you. looks kind of like this:
`set(get(a,'Children'),'ButtonDownFcn',{@clickevent,a});
function clickevent(hObject,eventdata,a)
h=get(a,'CurrentPoint');
end`